# Random forest regression error on GEE "No valid training data were found."

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

I'm using RF regression model on GEE. The output can be successfully generated but when I tried to make a "Variable Importance Histogram", the error happened and said **"Dictionary (Error) No valid training data were found"**

This is the code I typed:

```
// Get variable importance
var dict = classifier.explain();
print("Classifier information:", dict);
var variableImportance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(dict).get('importance'));
```

and this is the link to my script https://code.earthengine.google.com/070635503e0513c65e3c8ba773d77485
The random forest part starts from line 311

Comment: Your script isn't executable - `Cannot find required repo: users/sentinel2_import_resample/fail20230410:wrapper`. But your error message probably sums up your problem. Your training data set probably empty. I'd start by debuging line `253-266` - add to the map and print.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWiell. Yes, that is because I inserted the Sentinel1 preprocess scripts from https://github.com/adugnag/gee_s1_ard/tree/main/javascript
including all the packages inside. 
The output of RF is not visible on GEE map but when I downloaded it and input into QGIS, it is visible.